# Joomla 3 - Show category blog below single article

Tags: joomla

I would like to create a page where I have a single article and a category blog consisting of text and an image beneath. It should look like this:

[image: Website]

All articles should be dynamic, so that a user can change title, image and text.
How can I achieve this? I have one component tag. Is this possible with Joomla?

Best regards,

enne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a standard category layout where you have the category description displayed.  Just enter the text you always want to keep displayed in the description of the category.